# How to use a package's S4 classes in data/ scripts together with roxygen2?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4, roxygen2

I'm developing an R package providing several classes describing general life tables (https://github.com/kainhofer/r-valuation-tables). I'm also trying to provide data scripts that offer e.g. the Austrian annuity valuation tables using classes provided by the package.

The package itself works fine and installs properly. However, when I add .R scripts to the data/ directory that use classes defined in my package, then `roxygen` fails and complains that the S4 class is not an exported object from my namespace:

```
devtools::document()
```

> Updating ValuationTables documentation
>       Loading ValuationTables
>       Loading required package: ValuationTables
>       Fehler: 'valuationTable_period' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ValuationTables'

An example is the file https://github.com/kainhofer/r-valuation-tables/blob/master/data/ValuationTables_Austria_Annuities.R, where I even explicitly load my package, but `roxygen` still does not recognize the classes in my package's data scripts:

```
stopifnot(require(methods), require(utils), require(ValuationTables)) 
rr67.data = utils::read.csv("Austria_Annuities_RR67.csv", skip=2)

rr67 = ValuationTables::valuationTable_period(
  name = "ÖVM 59/61 RR67", ages = rr67.data$Alter, deathProbs = rr67.data$qx
);
```

If I leave out the `ValuationTables::` from the `valuationTable_period` call, then the error message is (translated from German):

```
devtools::document()
```

> Updating ValuationTables documentation
>       Loading ValuationTables
>       Loading required package: ValuationTables
>       Fehler in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
>           Unable to find function "valuationTable_period"

Using the `valuationTable_period` class in a normal R script works just fine:

```
library("ValuationTables", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3")
valuationTable_period(name="test", ages=0:10, deathProbs=(0:10)/10)
An object of class "valuationTable_period"
Slot "ages":
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
...
```

How can I make `roxygen2` properly detect / use the classes defined in my package?

Comment: scripts and csv files do not go in `data/`